# Footer is overextending

Tags: html, css

I need some help with my footer, its overextending horizontally, I've set the width to 100% so it should, in theory, be the size of the page. Any help would be much appreciated.

HTML

```
<footer>
<p>Mandurah Jetty Maintenance | Copyright &copy 2017</p>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer{
padding: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #333;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
overflow: hidden;


}
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you mean? What do you mean over-extending, if it goes right to the edge?

Comment: @EthanBristow Yes sure, here http://prntscr.com/ev2e1u  , you see that the footer extends making the page horizontally longer :(. You find any fix would be greatly appriciated. :)

Comment: you can try the work-break. here istruction https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the footer isn't reaching the far left/right of the page then change your css to this:

```
footer {
padding: 20px, 0px, 0px, 0px; //Top, right, bottom, left
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #333;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: @Bailee No problem, I'd appreciate it if you could accept the answer by clicking the tick button on the left side of this answer :)

Comment: Yep, i had to wait 10 minutes before i could do so, sorry for the wait, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Add `box-sizing:border-box;`
When adding `padding or border properties` to an `element` it by default increase the `width` and `height` of that element. So by adding `box-sizing:border-box` this stops that `increment` on following div still keeping the state of assigned padding and border.

> The box-sizing property is used to alter the default CSS box model
>   used to calculate width and height of the elements.

```css
footer{
padding: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #333;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
overflow: hidden;
box-sizing:border-box; /*Add this*/
}
```

```html
<footer>
<p>Mandurah Jetty Maintenance | Copyright &copy 2017</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: @Bailee Hope this help.

Comment: Welcome @Bailee :-)